# how do i use a javascript folder object

Tags: javascript, directory, photoshop, extendscript

I have been using a folder object as part of a script written in javascript and used for photoshop cs6 scripting.

My question regards the folder object

The cs6 javascript referance document says the following about folder objects

> "ExtendScript defines the JavaScript classes File and Folder to
>   encapsulate file-system references in a platform-independent manner;
>   see ‘JavaScript support in Adobe Photoshop CS6’ on page 32. For
>   references details of these classes, see the JavaScript Tools Guide."

(ExtendScript is Adobe’s extended implementation of JavaScript)

I am able to set the Folders directory by using something similar to Folder.setDialogue (the code is on my other PC so I cant remember what the exact method is
but this prompts the user to select a folder.

I want to hard code the folder location into the script

the documentation says that the folder object accepts the folder as a constructor but i cant make this work

i have tried code which looks something like

Folder(c:/some folder) and have tried replacing none text characters with their hexadecimal values but this has not worked ether.

How do i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var myfolder= Folder("path/to/folder");
if(myfolder.exists) alert("got it");
```

Should work. Take a look at the extend script toolkit and the object model viewer under help

Comment: Where do you find object model viewers?

Comment: In the help Menu of ESTK

Answer (score 1):

I too found this part of extendScript tricky and underdocumented.

Note that extendScript can express paths as URIs (escape all non-ascii!) and as system specific (Win/Mac - each of which have a different set of 'forbidden' characters).

The file object has two properties: `fullName` (a URI) and fsName (a file-system-specific path).

I *think* you have to pass a URI to the constructor, rather than a Windows/Mac path. So for: (Windows) `D:\foo\bar` use `/d/foo/bar`

Or you can get the open document file (if saved) as a starting point. This works for me in Illustrator:

```
var defaultFilename = "default.ai";
var fpath = app.activeDocument.fullName.path;
var myFolder = fpath || Folder.selectDialog ("Choose a Folder to export to");
if (myFolder === null) return

var myFilePath = myFolder + "/" + defaultFilename;
var myFile = new File(myFilePath).saveDlg("Export as", "Adobe Illustrator files:*.ai");
if (myFile === null) return
// if you get this far, myFile should be meaningful
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the fsName property. I wasn't aware of that. 
I want to import files via script in Premiere Pro and struggeling with the absolut path for the import especially since my code should work for Mac and Windows. So this helps me now a lot.